# Проблема зависимостей и пакетов ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, package, зависимости

Я пробую себя в программировании (конкретно в питоне) и неведомым мне образом что то испортил в пакетах. Сам гуглить пытался, находил лишь отдаленно похожее (я не про юзер linux и, пока что, не могу подстроить решение под себя). Поэтому спрашиваю у вас:

```
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета libpython3.6-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 пакет абсолютно неработоспособен; перед настройкой его
 следует переустановить
Отчёт apport не записан, так как сообщение об ошибке указывает на повторную ошибку от предыдущего отказа.
                                                                                                         dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет python3.6-dev:
 python3.6-dev зависит от libpython3.6-dev (= 3.6.7-1~18.04), однако:
  Пакет libpython3.6-dev:amd64 пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета python3.6-dev (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет libpython3-dev:amd64:
 libpython3-dev:amd64 зависит от libpython3.6-dev (>= 3.6.7-1~), однако:
  Пакет libpython3.6-dev:amd64 пока не настроен.

dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета libpython3-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
Отчёт apport не записан, так как сообщение об ошибке указывает на повторную ошибку от предыдущего отказа.
                                                                                                         При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 libpython3.6-dev:amd64
 python3.6-dev
 libpython3-dev:amd64
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.2.orig.tar.bz2: ЦЕЛ
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`Буду очень благодарен любой подсказке.

Comment: А что даёт ? > sudo apt install -f

Comment: Вы не приводите информацию о том, каким образом достигается такая ошибка.  Поскольку вы сказали, что у Вас Ubuntu, значит Вы должны использовать пакетный менеджер Synaptic. Или Вы работаете в командной строке? Подозреваю, что - второе. Это слишком сложно для новичка. Рекомендую Вам **снести** абсолютно всё, что вы установили вручную, запустить Synaptic и установить Python "в один клик".

Comment: Кстати говоря. в Ubuntu питон ставится по дефаульту. И устанавливать его дополнительно - не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю что именно вы сделали, но рискну предположить, что вы не учли, что в ubuntu по умолчанию установлен второй питон. И именно он вызывается командой python. Соответственно, команда pip также вызывает не тот pip, который вы хотите. Для установки пакетов используйте pip3, а для вызова интерпритатора python3. Например:

```
pip3 install your_lib

python3 your_file.py
```

Для отдельных проектов лучше использовать виртуальное окружение - изолированный интерпритатор, в который устанавливаются нужные вам зависимости. Создать виртуальное окружение можно вот такой командой

```
python3 -m venv venv_name
```

Затем виртуальное окружение нужно активировать

```
source path/to/your/venv/bin/activate
```

Внутри виртуального окружения ваш интерпритатор будет вызываться командой python, а пакетный менеджер командой pip, т.к. второго питона в нем не будет.